# JSON/Playframework invalid type

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, typesafe-stack

I'm having some troubles parsing a JSON response with Play 2.1 parser. Say I receive the following json as a string:

{"name": "myName"}

I'm able to parse it using these few lines...

```
case class MyJsonObj(name: String)
implicit val jsonRead = (
  (__ \ "name").read[String])(MyJsonObj.apply _)
val myObj = Json.parse("{\"name\": \"myName\"}").valide[MyJsonObj]
```

Now say I receive almost the same message but instead of having a string as "myName" I receive a null (i.e: {"name": null}), the parsing fails... Ideally, whenever I receive a null, I would like to put a default value (instead of raising an error) and keep parsing.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`readNullable`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsPath.scala#L262-L272) or `orElse`:

```scala
(__ \ 'name).readNullable[String].map(_.getOrElse("default"))
// Another solution:
(__ \ 'name).read[String] orElse Reads.pure("default")
```

Note: Readers don't work fine with "one-field" case class (but I suppose it's just for this example). Otherwise, see [this topic](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/918-play-21-json-issues#ticket-918-4).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up using the 2nd option.